# On the existence and uniqueness of the maximum likelihood estimators of a Student-t.

Tags: statistics, optimization, statistical-inference

Take the density of a generalized student-t, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
 p( y_t |  \sigma , \mu, \nu ) =  \frac {\Gamma (\frac {\nu +1}{2})}{\Gamma (\frac {\nu }{2}){\sqrt {\pi \nu }}{\sigma }\,}\left(1+{\frac {1}{\nu }}\left({\frac {y_t- \mu }{\sigma }}\right)^{2}\right)^{-\frac {\nu +1}{2}}
\end{align*}
and let the parameter we want to find a maximum likelihood estimator of be the scale $\sigma > 0$.

Then
\begin{align*}
\nabla \log p( y_t |  \sigma , \mu, \nu ) = - \frac{1}{\sigma} + (\nu +1) \left(  \frac{(y_t - \mu)^2 }{\nu \sigma^3}  \bigg/ 1 + \frac{1}{\nu} \left( \frac{y_t- \mu}{\sigma } \right)^2   \right)
\end{align*}

and the critical points can't be expressed in a closed-form. The EM algorithm is usually used to obtain an estimator.

Anyhow my question is: how do we know, in this case, that the maximum likelihood estimator exists and is unique? Is there a simple way to show this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, we have $$\sigma\cdot\nabla\log p=\frac{(\nu+1)(y_t-\mu)^2}{\nu\sigma^2+(y_t-\mu)^2}-1$$ whose root does have a closed form.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Exactly, how do I know that one of the roots will be a unique maximum? Is there an easy way? I now realize that the wording "maximum likelihood estimator" is confusing.

Comment: There is only one root, as $\sigma>0$. Find the sign of the second derivative at $\sigma^*$ where $\sigma^*$ solves $\nabla\log p=0$.